# (Passenger Agent) Signal received. Gracefully shutting down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger, rubber

I have a rails application that I am deploying on an aws ec2 instance, this is my first time using the Rubber Gem, for which I have followed [this tutorial](https://liggat.org/a-full-AWS-rails-stack-provision-and-deployment-with-the-rubber-gem/).
After removing the default nginx configurations and after intial deployment (step 5 of the tutorial I have mentioned) when ever I try and access my app using the public IP or DNS I get a 403 Forbidden nginx screen.
On inspecting the error log of nginx on the server this is what I found. I have been stuck on this issue for quite sometime now, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7236 13522/7fc24be3a780 age/Wat/Main.cpp:1264 ]: Starting PassengerAgent watchdog...
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7526 13525/7f2f7f588780 age/Hel/Main.cpp:944 ]: Starting PassengerAgent server...
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7529 13525/7f2f7f588780 age/Hel/Main.cpp:237 ]: PassengerAgent server running in multi-application mode.
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7550 13525/7f2f7f588780 age/Hel/Main.cpp:698 ]: PassengerAgent server online, PID 13525
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7851 13530/7f39b592e780 age/Log/Main.cpp:442 ]: Starting PassengerAgent logger...
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7863 13530/7f39b592e780 age/Log/Main.cpp:323 ]: PassengerAgent logger online, PID 13530
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7876 13525/7f2f7f588780 age/Hel/Main.cpp:857 ]: Watchdog seems to be killed; forcing shutdown of all subprocesses

[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7877 13525/7f2f79042700 age/Hel/Main.cpp:508 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
2015/07/10 05:49:13 [alert] 9729#0: Required key 'core_address' is missing (-1: Unknown error)
```

Answer (score -1):

Passenger author here. This error occurs when the Passenger module compiled inside Nginx, does not match the actual Passenger version that is installed. In other words, your installation is broken.

I recommend that you start over completely, on a new and empty server, using the [Passenger official walkthrough documentation.](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/)

Comment: actually this answer here on server fault worked for me, a change in version and my app on my instance is up and running 
http://serverfault.com/questions/704866/passenger-agent-signal-received-gracefully-shutting-down/705253#705253

Comment: any idea how can I deploy it in production using the link you provided???
I am deploying again following your link and when it comes to create a db its creating the development and test dbs and not the production db, I have added the secret key base as well.

Comment: Try `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: with a little more googling I found a link to deploy in production using capistrano, I have deployed the app but when I try and access it I get this error in the nginx logs (403 error):
"directory index of "<PATH>/current/" is forbidden....."